# Attach SQLITE Databaes in Zotero (i.e. Firefox XPCOM/XUL) extension

Tags: javascript, sqlite, firefox-addon, xpcom

I'm working on an extension for Zotero which still uses the old XPCOM/XUL system.  I need to store a bunch of data for the extension so, worried that modifying the primary database would create problems, I planned on following the example plugin and creating a new sqlite database of my own.  However, I want to be able to join tables in the database I create with tables in the default Zotero database.

Is there a way to use Sqlite.jsm (or some other component) to ATTACH my database to the main zotero database?  If not I'm open to other suggestions.

I'm flying a bit in the dark here since the shift to WebExtensions has made it a bit tougher to find introductory documentation for the old style extension system.

Answer (score 1):

You can just execute the ATTACH command using the existing zotero DB connection.